# Argument of type 'string | Blob | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | Blob'

Tags: javascript, typescript, syntax-error

Comlete error:

> Argument of type 'string | Blob | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | Blob'.
> Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string | Blob'.ts(2345)

```
for(const value in values) {
      if(typeof values[value] != undefined)formData.append(value, values[value])
    }
```

also, values have a type :

```
type Props = {
    userName: string
    firstName?: string
    lastName?: string
    email?: string
    password: string
    picturePath?: Blob 
    [index:string]: string | Blob | undefined
}
```

Update:
I fixed it, like this:

```
      for(const value in values) {
      if(value){
        const check = values[value]
        if(typeof(check) !== "undefined"){
          formData.append(value, check)
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: You'll need to assign the `values[value]` to a `const` before the condition for typescript to accurately track it.